# Foreach statement to mix content type in presentation

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, feed

I have a news feed where I would like to show mixed content which contains three different types of items. Lets say these are blog posts (type 1), ads (type 2), and articles(type 3).

I pull the data for each item type, which is an array containing different data about the item (e.g. author, text, date etc.).

So I have array1, array2, array3.

I would like to know how can I mix the three inside the foreach statement, so that they are displayed in a mixed sequence, i.e. type1, type2, type3 than again, as opposed to displaying all items from type 1 then all items from type 2 and so on.

I have done:

```
$contentArray = array(

    0 => $array1,
    1 => $array2,
    2 => $array3
);
foreach($contentArray  as $itemType){
if($itemType == $array1){
//display template 1
}elseif($itemType == $array2)
//display template 2
}else{
//display template 2
}
```

However that displays all of array1 first, then array2 and so on.

How to structure the foreach statement so that content is mixed?

Comment: please share your expected output. It seems bit unclear.

Comment: The output should be: itemTyp1, itemTyp2, itemTyp3, itemTyp1, itemTyp2, itemTyp3, itemTyp1, itemTyp2, itemTyp3, , so on

Answer (score 0):

When iterating through an array there is an index - so assuming that the indices of the arrays correspond from array to array then you could try something along the lines of:-

```
<?php
    foreach( $array1 as $index => $value ){
        echo $value .' '.$array2[ $index ]. ' '. $array3[ $index ];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want random values, you can try the below code:

```
$array1 =  array('1' => 'item1' , '2' => 'item2', '3' => 'item3');
$array2 =  array('1' => 'item1' , '2' => 'item2', '3' => 'item3');
$array3 =  array('1' => 'item1' , '2' => 'item2', '3' => 'item3');

foreach( $array1 as $index => $value ){
         $a = array(1,2,3);
         shuffle($a);
         echo $array1[$a[0]].' '.$array2[$a[1]].' '.$array3[$a[2]];
}
```